# How to verify if there is an overlap between time windows

Tags: python, datetime

You are given a list of pairs. Each pair stores the start and end date representing a time window. The task is to verify if there is any overlap.

Note that the problem could trivially be solved using two nested for loops looping through `periods` and a few if conditions to verify the absence of overlaps. However, I'm interested to see if there is a more readable and elegant solution which keeps for loops and if statements at its minimum and which does not necessarily uses the standard library.

Overlaps don't necessarily occur between adjacent entries.

The list `periods` is expected to have less than 10 time-windows. I'm not concerned about CPU time. I'm concerned about code readability.

```
from datetime import datetime

overlapping_periods = [
    [datetime(2019, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 5)],
    [datetime(2019, 1, 6), datetime(2019, 1, 10)],
    [datetime(2019, 1, 9), datetime(2019, 1, 15)],
]
non_overlapping_periods = [
    [datetime(2019, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 5)],
    [datetime(2019, 1, 6), datetime(2019, 1, 10)],
    [datetime(2019, 1, 11), datetime(2019, 1, 15)],
]

# Find an elegant `verify_overlaps`.
verify_overlaps(overlapping_periods)  # True
verify_overlaps(non_overlapping_periods)  # False
```

Comment: What assumptions can you make?  Are the overlaps always like what you've shown...the overlap always occurs between adjacent entries in the list?  If so, this would be very simple.  I'm guessing you'd have already thought of that, and that the overlapping entries don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: Edited. Overlaps don't necessarily occur between adjacent entries.

Comment: One approach is to first sort the list by the start date.

Comment: If you don't don't care about performance, what's more readable than the two loop approach?  If you can only have at most 10 entries, I would suggest that you not overthink this.  With that said, I do think it's an interesting question to pose, and there likely is a more efficient algorithm.  I can't think, however, how there will be one that is more readable than the two loop thing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that's a great idea.  I was just about to say that too.  Then you'd just walk through the list and keep track of the end date and compare it to the next start date.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this simple, or am I missing something?

```
def verify_overlaps(s):
    s = sorted(s) # sorts on first member of each element by default
    current = datetime.min
    for dt0, dt1 in s:
        if dt0 <= current:
            return False
        current = dt1
    return True
```

You didn't specify if the start of one period matching the end of another period is considered an overlap.  That's just a matter of "<" vs "<=".

Comment: You can drop the `key` argument in `sorted`. Initialize `current` to datetime.min. Use double index as Mstaino did in the loop. I was hoping for a more readable solution but that's probably the best we could do unless someone finds an implementation in the std library.

Comment: all good suggestions.  I only hesitate to take out the `key` argument because of readability...needing to know what `sorted` does when given lists as items to be sorted.  But I guess a comment will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `sorted` function, which returns an iterable (by default, it will sort by the first argument in your list):

```
def verify_overlap(periods):
    d2_previous = datetime(1900,1,1)
    for d1, d2 in (sorted(periods)):
        if d1 <= d2_previous:
            return False
        d2_previous = d2
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you consider this more readable, but:

```
import itertools
from typing import NamedTuple


class Period(NamedTuple):
    start: datetime
    end: datetime

    def __and__(self, other):
        return (
            other.start in self or
            self.start in other
        )

    def __contains__(self, dt):
        return dt >= self.start and dt < self.end


def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def verify_overlaps(periods):
    return any(a & b for a, b in pairwise(sorted(periods)))
```